# How to save the exported PDF in Telerik Report in an online location?

Tags: telerik, filestream, telerik-reporting

so I have successfully exported my Telerik Report into a PDF file and that PDF file will be saved into a local server my computer is connected to. I used System.IO.Filestream to save it, now I want to ask if it's possible to save the report to an online location, something like mywebsite.com/Reports/samplePDFFile1.pdf also using the Filestream? or Am I going to use another set of codes? If yes, what is it? Thanks! The following codes are the ones that I used

```
 filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("\\server01\Reports", fileName)

    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
        fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length)
    End Using
```

Additional information:
Telerik Report Version Q3 2014 8.2.14.1027
VB.Net

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mapped/shared folder path to that target website, you should be able to save it they way you are trying with "\server01\Reports".  However if you want to save to a remote path through HTTP protocol, that will not be possible, or easy/direct from my knowledge.  You will have to create a page that accepts an upload, and then that page will accept the file and save it where ever it is programmed to.  If I was in your position, I would have preferred creating a webservice to accept a byte array (which would've contained the pdf file bytes) and have that save it to the target server, IF internal network access was not possible.  But I know there are a other things to consider in terms of securing the webservice, etc, and you will be best judge to finalize what design suits you.  HTH